How to display an image from an Url in a post in Wordpress?
I am trying to create a page to edit in Gutenberg with a text and an image. The image has to be downloaded in the media ( from the url ) and displayed in the page I generated.
I tried to download the image and insert the media in the library. When I use my url in the json data : "my_site_url/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/wooster_sur-mesure_1_3x-1-4545.webp\\" , it works but I want to display the URL origin :
$image_url = 'https://cdn-img.wooster.fr/app/uploads/2023/09/wooster_sur-mesure_1_3x-1.webp?lossy=1&ssl=1&w=500';
The url is unknown.
     * Function to download image from URL
     *  @param string $image_url The URL of the image to download
    * @param string $image_alt The alt text for the image
     */
    public function download_image($image_url)
    {
        $image_url = 'https://cdn-img.wooster.fr/app/uploads/2023/09/wooster_sur-mesure_1_3x-1.webp?lossy=1&ssl=1&w=500';
        //Download the image if it doesn't already exist
        $attachment_id = $this->get_attachment_id_by_url($image_url);
        if ($attachment_id) {
            // If the image already exists, return his id
            return $attachment_id;
        }
        // It downloads the image from the URL
        $image = media_sideload_image($image_url);
        return $image;
    }
    /***
     * To insert the media in library and get the attachment id
     *
     */
    public function insert_to_media($image_url)
    {
        //Put the downloaded image into the variable $image
        $image = $this->download_image($image_url);

        // Then insert the $image into the media library
        $attachment = wp_insert_attachment(array(
            'post_title' => 'Image Wooster téléchargée',
            'post_content' => 'Image wooster',
            'post_status' => 'draft',
        ), $image);

        // Generate metadata for the image
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment, $image);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment, $attach_data);

        return $attachment;
    }

    /***
     * Function to get attachment ID by URL with a personalized query
     * @param $image_url
     */
    public function get_attachment_id_by_url($image_url)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $attachment_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s'", $image_url));
        return $attachment_id;
    }
    /**
     * Function to create a post with the content of the JSON data
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function create_post()
    {
        // Check if the form has been submitted
        if (isset($_POST['submit-gutenberg']) && $_POST['submit-gutenberg'] === 'gutenberg') {
            // Retrieve the JSON data
            $json_data = '{
                "__file": "wp_block",
                "title": "Partenariat Wooster",
                "content": "<!-- wp:paragraph -->\\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eget vehicula orci, ut iaculis ex. Donec sed ornare nisi. Donec non sollicitudin ex. Aliquam at leo non odio hendrerit consectetur. Sed porttitor lacus placerat metus viverra facilisis. Aenean gravida ornare purus, ut posuere lectus dictum a. Nunc nisi leo, porta ut porta et, porttitor quis ante. In id arcu in sem vulputate fermentum. Vivamus libero augue, finibus id eros in, gravida vestibulum ex. Quisque ultrices, odio et consectetur vestibulum, arcu mi elementum nulla, a elementum massa libero quis nibh. Aenean pulvinar diam sem, a auctor nisl ullamcorper at.</p>\\n<!-- /wp:paragraph -->\\n\\n<!-- wp:image {\\"id\\":10217,\\"sizeSlug\\":\\"full\\",\\"linkDestination\\":\\"none\\"} -->\\n<figure class=\\"wp-block-image size-full\\"><img src=\\"my_site_url/wp-content/uploads/2024/04/wooster_sur-mesure_1_3x-1-4545.webp\\" alt=\\"\\" class=\\"wp-image-10217\\"/></figure>\\n<!-- /wp:image -->",
                "syncStatus": "draft"

            }';

            // Decode the JSON data
            $data = json_decode($json_data, true);
            $data['content'] = str_replace('my_site_url', esc_url( home_url() ), $data['content']);

            // Extraire l'URL de l'image
            preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $data['content'], $matches);
            $image_url = $matches[1];

            // Download the image from the URL to the media library
            media_sideload_image($image_url, 'Image téléchargée depuis l\'URL');

            // Create the post content Gutenberg block
            $post_content = $data['content'];


            // Data for the post
            $post_data = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post_status' => 'draft',
                'post_title' => $data['title'],
                'post_content' => $post_content,
            );

            // Insert those data by creating a post page
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

            // Check if the post has been created
            if ($post_id) {
                // Get the edit post link
                $edit_post_link = admin_url("post.php?post=$post_id&action=edit");

                if ($edit_post_link) {
                    // Redirect to the edit post page
                    wp_redirect($edit_post_link);
                    exit();
                }
            } else {
                // Check if the post creation failed
                echo "La création du post a échoué.";
                exit();
            }}`


Here are a few problems you have in your code

media_sideload_image does not return the path to the downloaded image; it returns HTML code or a WP_Error on failure. You need to handle this properly.
wp_insert_attachment requires a file path to insert an image properly into the media library, not an HTML string.
The image URL needs handling and manipulation before using it due to possible query strings that aren't part of the actual file name.

I fixed your code a little bit
class YourClass {
  /**
   * Function to download an image from a URL and add it to the media library
   * @param string $image_url URL of the image
   * @return int|WP_Error The attachment ID on success, WP_Error on failure
   */
  public function download_image($image_url) {
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
      require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
  
      // Check if the image already exists
      $attachment_id = $this->get_attachment_id_by_url($image_url);
      if ($attachment_id) {
          return $attachment_id;
      }
  
      // Remove any query strings from the URL
      $image_url = strtok($image_url, '?');
      // Sideload image returns an HTML img tag on success
      $file = media_sideload_image($image_url, 0, null, 'src');
      if (is_wp_error($file)) {
          return $file; // Return the error if media_sideload_image failed
      }
  
      $attachment_id = $this->get_attachment_id_by_url($file); // Get the ID of the newly added image
      if (!$attachment_id) {
          return new WP_Error('failed_to_retrieve_attachment', "Échec de l'extraction de l'ID de la pièce jointe.");
      }
  
      return $attachment_id;
  }
  
  /**
   * Helper function to get an attachment ID given a URL
   * @param string $url
   * @return int|bool The attachment ID or false if not found
   */
  public function get_attachment_id_by_url($url) {
      global $wpdb;
      $attachment = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid = %s", $url));
      return $attachment ? (int) $attachment : false;
  }
  
  /**
   * Function to create a Gutenberg post with a specific image and text
   */
  public function create_post() {
      $image_url = 'https://cdn-img.wooster.fr/app/uploads/2023/09/wooster_sur-mesure_1_3x-1.webp';
      $attachment_id = $this->download_image($image_url);
  
      if (is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
          echo "Erreur de téléchargement de l'image : " . $attachment_id->get_error_message();
          return;
      }
  
      $image_html = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full');
  
      // Construct post content with proper Gutenberg block structure
      $post_content = <<<HTML
      <!-- wp:paragraph -->
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...</p>
      <!-- /wp:paragraph -->
  
      <!-- wp:image {"id":{$attachment_id},"sizeSlug":"full"} -->
      <figure class="wp-block-image size-full">{$image_html}</figure>
      <!-- /wp:image -->
      HTML;
  
      $post_data = [
          'post_type'    => 'page',
          'post_status'  => 'draft',
          'post_title'   => 'Partenariat Wooster',
          'post_content' => $post_content,
      ];
  
      $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);
  
      if ($post_id) {
          echo "Post créé avec succès! Editer <a href='" . admin_url("post.php?post=$post_id&action=edit") . "'>ici</a>.";
      } else {
          echo "La création du post a échoué";
      }
  }
}


Thank you a lot! I had an error on Wordpress " This block contains unexpected or invalid content" but I removed : $image_html = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'full'); and modify  `$post_content = <<<HTML

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...

<!-- wp:image {"id":{$attachment_id},"sizeSlug":"full"} -->
<figure class="wp-block-image size-full"><img src="{$image_url}" alt="Description for the image"></figure>
<!-- /wp:image -->
HTML;`  so it can be a image block and it works !

